# Is it possible to let fadeOut maintain the height of your element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding random background images to my site. I put a camera icon in the lower left of my page, and when the user hovers over the icon it hides everything else on my page so you can view the background image. The problem is, when I call the jQuery `fadeOut` function, it loses the vertical scrollbar and then resizes my image to stretch across that part of the screen as well. It looks like a glitch, but I know it's because I lose my vertical scrollbar during my `fadeOut` function call.

Is there a similar call to fadeOut which will hide my content, but not lose the scrollbar? I know that I can set the scrollbar to always be on my screen, but I don't want that seeing as some of my pages don't need it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery `$.fadeOut` fades out the opacity on an element and then sets it to `display: none;` when it is finished.  That causes the element to disappear along with it's scrollbar.

Instead, you can use `$.animate`:

```
$('#myEl').animate({opacity:0});
```

to hide the element and then:

```
$('#myEl').animate({opacity:1});
```

to show it again.

Using this will not mess with layout, just transparency.

**[Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/j6Pcb/2/) showing the glitch.**

**[And here's one](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/j6Pcb/1/) that works better.**

Comment: You sir, are a genius. I'm still pretty new to jQuery, so I haven't had much experience with the animate function. Thanks!

Comment: Both demo link no longer valid

Answer (score 5):

instead of using fadeout , use `fadeto`

```
.fadeTo( "slow", 0 );
```

https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: This should be the approved answer as it uses jQuery's library methods and allows you to take advantage of the complete function. Simple and clean.

Comment: How do we fade it back in?

Answer (score 2):

fadeOut function adds display:none at the end of the animation. You can do the fade animation manually:

```
element.animate({opacity: 0}, 'normal');
```

Also you can add a callback at the end of the animation, for example, to give visibility: hidden; (is not the same that display:none.

```
element.animate({opacity: 0}, 'normal', function(e){element.css('visibility', 'hidden');});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank div of the same size before you fade the rest of the items out?

Comment: Question? Or comment?

Comment: Answer, in the form of a question. Like Jeopardy.

Comment: @Jay: oh the delicious irony... ;)

Comment: Awww @Aboba, I'm sorry. You forgot to say "What is add a blank div of the same size before you fade the rest of the items out?"